# How to increment a variable in a Golang template?

Tags: go-templates

I am looping over an array using `{{ range $index, $entry }}`.  I need to use `$index + 1` in the template.  I am just learning templates, and I am surprised to discover that there's apparently no `add` function or capability.

How can I increment `$index` (or create a new variable that is equal to `$index + 1` at each iteration of the `range`?

Comment: You may register custom functions, including an `add()` functionality. Then you may call those functions in templates.